# QR code detection via zbar

Tags: detection, zbar

I am able to decode the QR code via zbar 0.10, however, I don't know how to detect the QR code. I know that in the processing pipeline, detection should be achieved first before decoding can take place successfully. I also don't find any corresponding interface in the zbar API that can do that. Anyone can point me to any or would like to give some thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ZBar should find the QR code in the image and report the results without you telling it to first detect the QR code. In other words, just feed it the image with the QR code in it somewhere and ZBar will find it.